# how can I stretch multiple labels in the same line

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have 4 different `labels` in my View like this[image]

the labels which are in blue color are dynamic and their values comes from the database. So I want to do something like  if there is any country comes whose characters are larger then this 'London,It' then it should stretches his position to fit the area and the words or labels in front of them should also change their position according to the backward label and also If  somehow line ends then move to the second line if it can be possible. I am doing this in TableView cell. I have used `sizeToFit` Property but it doesn't give me required result.

Comment: Make it a single `UILabel` and use `NSAttributedString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have better solution than using multiple label. You can use a single label and set attributed string to the label. You can give any attribute to the string as per your requirements. For setting the particular color to the perticula word you can set the color attribute to that string.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to make one label that goes across the screen, and set the `lines` value to 0, which will make it wrap to a second line if the text is too long to fit on one line.  Then, instead of having the 4 values in separate labels you can set the text of that one label to something like this:

```
let labelText = "From \(self.departureCity) To \(self.arrivalCity)"
```

where "self.departureCity" and "self.arrivalCity" are the values of your database search.

The only problem with this approach comes if you really want the city values to be in blue like they are in your example - if that's what you really want you'll have to mess with the `attributedText` property.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use, a single label with merged NSString and set attributed string to the label.